# Invoke not switching back to separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I have the method below that is running on a separate thread from the main UI thread, and I am trying to update the `ListBox` control on the main thread. The code does work and the field does get updated, but when the `Invoke` method runs it switches to the main thread. The problem is that the code after the `Invoke` also runs on the main thread, but I need it to run on the separate thread.

```
    public static void Status_Message(string str, int destination, int prompt)
    {
        //Clear_System_Message_Area();

        sysmsg++;
        ListBox tl = Application.OpenForms["GMLEC"].Controls["groupBox2"].Controls["TestList"] as ListBox;
        if (!tl.InvokeRequired)
        {
            tl.Items.Add(str);
            tl.Refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            tl.Invoke(new Action<string, int, int>(Status_Message), str, destination, prompt);
        }

        if (destination == 1)
        {
            Printer.Output(str);
        }

        if (prompt == 1)
        {
            Pause(false);
        }

        if (sysmsg > 23)
        {
            Pause(true);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to make it go back to the separate thread?

Comment: Easy, don't invoke the entire function, invoke only what you need invoked. I also feel that everyone who invokes synchronously should have to defend their choice in front of a jury of their peers who have to unanimously approve, or they need to fix their code.

Comment: How do you know that the code before the `tl.Invoke` line runs on a background thread, and after this line it runs on the main UI thread? I don't see the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` to be logged somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want code run on the UI thread, don't invoke the method that contains it.

For what it's worth, I disagree with any code that uses `InvokeRequired`. First of all, you ought to know from the context whether invoke is required or not. If you don't know which thread the code that's executing is on, then there is too much coupling between the UI and background task parts of the code.

But secondly, the `Control.Invoke()` method has to check which thread is current anyway, because it has to work whether you are on the UI thread or not. You can always call it safely from the UI thread, and when you do, it can't go queueing up your delegate for invocation and then waiting for it, because that would deadlock. It has to just invoke the delegate directly, but only in that case, which means it's doing the `InvokeRequired` check anyway.

So, taking all of that into account, just write your code to always invoke the part that needs invoking, and be done with it.

For example:

```cs
public static void Status_Message(string str, int destination, int prompt)
{
    //Clear_System_Message_Area();

    sysmsg++;

    ListBox tl = Application.OpenForms["GMLEC"].Controls["groupBox2"].Controls["TestList"] as ListBox;

    tl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
    {

        tl.Items.Add(str);
        tl.Refresh();
    }));

    if (destination == 1)
    {
        Printer.Output(str);
    }

    if (prompt == 1)
    {
        Pause(false);
    }

    if (sysmsg > 23)
    {
        Pause(true);
    }
}
```

Now, some other notes about this:

- It's doubtful that you should be calling `Refresh()`. Let Winforms deal with updating on its own. If you've somehow interfered with it refreshing the window normally, fix *that*. Don't hack around it by calling `Refresh()` yourself.
- It's almost certain that there's a better way to encapsulate the `ListBox` object than by always looking it up from the top of the UI control graph. For example, maybe the actual object should have been referenced directly (e.g. from a `TestList` field) and passed to the code that will eventually need it.
- Finally, and most important, the fact that you're using `Invoke()` at all is a big warning flag in modern code. There's a decent chance that your overall code could be refactored to use async/await in a way that allows it to read more naturally and still work correctly, but at the very least it would be better to use `Progress<T>` to mediate cross-thread updates like this.

To address any of these issues would be beyond the scope of the current question, but I do encourage you to take the suggestions under consideration.

Answer (score -2):

This might help...

normally I use `Invoke()` to activate a part of the script after a certain time. `Invoke()` Does NOT repeat, if you want it to repeat you can use `InvokeRepeating()`.

another option is to use "Multi-Threading". Here's how to use Multi-Threading:

```
using System.Threading

public static Thread newThread = new Thread(MultiThread)

private void Start()
{
newThread.Start()
//also newThread.Abort() to quit the thread
}

private static void MultiThread()
{
    // this is the seporate thread
    // i normally use this for a "while (True)" loop cause it will stop responding 
    //otherwise

}
```

srry for any typos

Hopefully this helps